# How to open Chrome Extensions page from options.html from my own extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my options page for my Chrome Extension I placed a link directing users to the Chrome general settings page for extensions. This one:

[image]

I used the following html:

```
<a href="chrome://extensions/" id="idLnkSettings">Settings</a>
```

But it doesn't do anything when I click it.

What is the URL that I need there?

Comment: When I click it, I get the following message in the JS console: `Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://extensions/ ` - It wouldn't surprise me if it's not a page you can navigate to without explicitly entering the addr in the addr bar - i.e, no link will take you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it to work. Here it is for whoever is interested, using jQuery:

```
//Set Settings link (from onLoad event handler)
$("#idLnkSettings").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    chrome.windows.create({
        url: "chrome://extensions/"
    });
});
```

Comment: I would personally use `chrome.tabs.create`, why a new window?